# React.js How to make a global win counter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to programming and am creating my first application, a card game. Can you tell me how I can improve my code? I am also stuck at one point and do not understand how to display the global win counter. For example, if in this game the computer scored 10 points and won, and in the next 15 more points the global counter should show 25.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import './App.css';
import Start from "./components/Start";
import Game from "./components/Game";
import Result from "./components/Result";
import {game, result, start} from "./utils/constants";

class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            page: start,
            name: 'You',
            compWins: 0,
            playerWins: 0,
            countWinsPlayer: 0,
            countWinsComp: 0
        }
    }



     changePage = page => {
        this.setState({page});
     }

    changeName = name => {
        this.setState({name});
    }

    changeResult = (compWins, playerWins, countWinsPlayer,countWinsComp) => {
        this.setState({compWins, playerWins,countWinsPlayer,countWinsComp})
    }


    render() {
        switch (this.state.page) {
            case game:
                return <Game
                    name={this.state.name}
                    switchPage={this.changePage}
                    setResult={this.changeResult}/>;
            case result:
                return <Result
                    switchPage={this.changePage}
                    compWins={this.state.compWins}
                    playerWins={this.state.playerWins}
                    countWinsPlayer={this.state.countWinsPlayer}
                    countWinsComp={this.state.countWinsComp}
                    />;
            default:
                return <Start
                    switchName={this.changeName}
                    switchPage={this.changePage}/>;
        }
    }
}

export default App;
```

Start.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {game} from "../utils/constants";

class Start extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: ''
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Ready for war</h1>
                <input
                    onChange={(e) => this.setState({name: e.target.value})}
                    value={this.state.name}
                    type='text'
                    placeholder='Enter your name'/>
                <button onClick={() => {
                    this.props.switchPage(game);
                    this.props.switchName(this.state.name)
                }}>Start</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Start;
```

Game.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {deck, result, shuffle} from "../utils/constants";

class Game extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            playerCard: 'Player card',
            compCard: 'Computer card',
            compWins: 0,
            playerWins: 0,
            countWinsPlayer: 0,
            countWinsComp: 0
        };
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        const cards = shuffle(deck);
        this.compCards = cards.slice(0, deck.length / 2);
        this.playerCards = cards.slice(deck.length / 2, deck.length);
    }

    handleClickNext = () => {
        if (this.playerCards.length) {
            const player = this.playerCards.pop();
            const comp = this.compCards.pop();

            if (player.rank > comp.rank) {
                //this.setState({playerWins: this.state.playerWins + 1});
                this.setState((state, props) => ({playerWins: state.playerWins + 1}));
                this.setState((state, props) => ({countWinsPlayer: state.countWinsPlayer + 1}));

            }
            if (player.rank < comp.rank) {
                this.setState({compWins: this.state.compWins + 1});
                this.setState({countWinsComp: this.state.countWinsComp + 1});
            }
            this.setState({
                playerCard: `${player.rank}, ${player.suit}`,
                compCard: `${comp.rank}, ${comp.suit}`
            });
        } else {
            this.props.setResult(this.state.compWins, this.state.playerWins, this.state.countWinsPlayer, this.countWinsComp);
            this.props.switchPage(result);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Computer</h1>
                <p>{this.state.compCard}</p>
                <p>{this.state.playerCard}</p>
                <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.handleClickNext}>Next</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Game;
```

Result.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {game} from "../utils/constants";

const Result = ({playerWins, compWins, switchPage, countWinsPlayer,countWinsComp}) => {
    const getResult = () => {
        if (playerWins > compWins) {
            return 'WIN';
        }
        if (playerWins < compWins) {
            return 'LOSE';
        }
        return 'DRAW';
    };
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{getResult()}</h1>
            <h3>This game:</h3>
            <h3>Your wins {playerWins} - {compWins} Computer wins</h3>
            <h3>Total wins:</h3>
            <h3>Your wins {countWinsPlayer} - {countWinsComp} Computer wins</h3>
            <button onClick={() => switchPage(game)}>Again ?</button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Result;
```

constans.js

```
export const start = 'Home';
export const game = 'Game';
export const result = 'Result';
export const createDeck = () => {
    const deck = [];
    const suits = ['spade', 'club', 'diamond', 'heart'];
    for (let i = 0; i < suits.length; i++){
        for (let j = 1; j <= 13; j++){
            deck.push({rank: j, suit: suits[i]});
        }
    }
    return deck;
};
export const deck = createDeck();
export const shuffle = arr => {
    const res = [...arr];
    res.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
    return res;
}
```

Comment: You can persist react state to local storage, read it into the initial state when the app starts. Also, can you clarify what constitutes "global win count"? Since you didn't say this code isn't working and there are no errors it sounds like you may be looking for more of a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @DrewReese "global win count" - For example, if in this game the computer scored 10 points and won, and in the next 15 more points the global counter should show 25. I mean this by a global counter and I don't quite know how to make it right. If you could help me I would be grateful

Comment: @DrewReese Yes that's right

Comment: What is the difference between `compWins` and `countWinsComp`? They seem like duplicate data.

Comment: @DrewReese There is no difference at the moment. My problem is that I do not know how to make the data in the "State" called "countWinsComp" persist after the end of the game and go to the next game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use localStorage to persist your application/game state.

It appears that `App` is the main component holding game state and passing state/callbacks to each "page". We can start by implementing lifecycle methods to initialize state from localStorage and update it after each game.

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      page: start,
      name: "You",
      // result from last game
      compWins: 0,
      playerWins: 0,
      // total wins
      countWinsComp: 0,
      countWinsPlayer: 0,
    };
  }

  // Read from localStorage and initialize state
  componentDidMount() {
    const gameState = localStorage.getItem("gameState");
    if (gameState) {
      this.setState(JSON.parse(gameState));
    }
  }

  // If total game wins count updates, persist to localStorage
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { countWinsComp, countWinsPlayer } = this.state;
    const gameState = { countWinsComp, countWinsPlayer };

    if (
      prevState.countWinsComp !== countWinsComp ||
      prevState.countWinsPlayer !== countWinsPlayer
    ) {
      localStorage.setItem("gameState", JSON.stringify(gameState));
    }
  }

  ...

  // Change here to only consume the wins from the last game
  // Update the totals and store the last wins for the result display
  changeResult = (compWins, playerWins) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      countWinsPlayer: prevState.countWinsPlayer + playerWins,
      countWinsComp: prevState.countWinsComp + compWins,
      compWins,
      playerWins
    }));
  };

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Game.jsx

Here we need only store the wins for the current game. This is reset each time a game starts and `Game` is mounted. The change here is to just update the current game score and only pass the current score to the `setResult` callback.

```
class Game extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      playerCard: "Player card",
      compCard: "Computer card",
      // current game score
      compWins: 0,
      playerWins: 0
    };
  }

  ...

  handleClickNext = () => {
    if (this.playerCards.length) {
      const player = this.playerCards.pop();
      const comp = this.compCards.pop();

      if (player.rank > comp.rank) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          playerWins: prevState.playerWins + 1
        }));
      }
      if (player.rank < comp.rank) {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({ compWins: prevState.compWins + 1 }));
      }
      this.setState({
        playerCard: `${player.rank}, ${player.suit}`,
        compCard: `${comp.rank}, ${comp.suit}`
      });
    } else {
      this.props.setResult(this.state.compWins, this.state.playerWins);
      this.props.switchPage(result);
    }
  };

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

## Demo

[image: Edit react-js-how-to-make-a-global-win-counter]